# Android - event log activity launch time

Tags: android

I see below output in event logcat when launching an activity.

```
I/activity_launch_time( 2239): [1116751776,com.android.email/.activity.MessageListXL,980,1195]
I/activity_launch_time( 2239): [1117104040,com.android.email/.activity.MessageListXL,870,1636]
I/activity_launch_time( 2239): [1118231336,com.android.email/.activity.MessageListXL,655,1323]
I/activity_launch_time( 2239): [1116726352,com.android.email/.activity.MessageListXL,758,1437]
I/activity_launch_time( 2239): [1137954344,com.android.email/.activity.MessageListXL,1043,1693]
```

and from function prototype

```
writeActivityLaunchTime(int token, String componentName, long time)
```

I think token is 1116751776 in output.
Is time argument the time taken to launch activity? and in logcat which number is launch time? 980 or 1195?

Comment: Another question: For what you need this information?

Comment: To check launch time of any app, if that event log is reliable way to check.

Comment: With  launch time you mean the duration or the startup?

Comment: yes, duration of startup before application loads any content. The above log gets printed after empty views are shown and before application starts to load content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer in ActivityRecord.java.

```
EventLog.writeEvent(EventLogTags.AM_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_TIME,
                            userId, System.identityHashCode(this), shortComponentName,
                            thisTime, totalTime);
```

'thisTime' is activity launch time. 'totaltime' seems to be something related to activity stack. not sure what that means.

Comment: Here's the Android source code in question: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityRecord.java#L832

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
public static void writeActivityLaunchTime(int token, String componentName, long time) {
    android.util.EventLog.writeEvent(ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_TIME, token, componentName, time);
}
```

Comment: I did and it didn't help as code has 2 numbers in arguments but logcat has 3.

Comment: The first parameter is a constant value that represent the time you launched the activity. for example 2pm

Comment: I doubt that since it is randomly increasing and decreasing at every launch. So I was guessing it to be random token.

Comment: When you launch your activity isnt the first parameter your actual time?

Comment: Guess not. updated the question to show logs from five successive launches of email app.