# Meaning of am_activity_launch_time?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I am seeking a way to measure launch times of general apps in Android, and happen to know that

```
adb logcat -b events | grep am_activity_launch_time
```

might be one answer.

But I failed to find out what duration the command above shows (i.e., from what event to what event). Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - event log activity launch time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266037/android-event-log-activity-launch-time)

Comment: According to an answer [in this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266037/android-event-log-activity-launch-time), the second to last parameter is the total time for drawing to complete after launching the activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command

```
cmd0=add logcat -c
```

to clear the logs and then execute the below command
`cmd1 = "grep am_activity_launch_time Example.txt | grep com.example.example| cut -d ',' -f4-4 > Example.csv"`

The values are then saved in a csv file.
Then you can the python commands

```
os.system(cmd0);
os.system(cmd2);
```

Then use matplotlib to plot the graph from the generated csv files.

```
axes=plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([1,20])
axes.set_ylim([0,4000])

plt.title("Performance Analysis ")
plt.ylabel('Time in milliseconds')
plt.xlabel('Number of itirations (DEVICE:Samsung Galaxy Note 4)')
data1=np.genfromtxt("Example.csv)"

plt.plot(data1,label="Example",linewidth=2.0,color='m')

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1),loc=1,borderaxespad=0.)


plt.show()
```

Once this is done execute this file in the python cmd.

Answer (score 0):

adb logcat -b all | egrep -n --color 'Displayed *'

> 12461:11-26 22:43:05.316  1110  1167 I ActivityTaskManager: Displayed mobi.goldendict.android.free/mobi.goldendict.android.GoldenDict: +1s494ms

You could measure app launches time in android by this.